# Strongloop LoopBack Change-Stream puts terms in its response before JSON?

Tags: android, json, loopbackjs, strongloop

My response from the change stream API of loopback is

```
:ok

 event: data
 data: {"target":42,"data": {"text":"string","number":0,"isNewInstance":true,"created":1458493863596,"edited":1458493863596},"type":"create"}
```

and each time I call the API it generates

```
 event: data
 data:
```

before my Json and destroys my ability to parse my JSON  response, does anyone know anything about the Strongloop loopback API, such as filtering..etc that will help me fix this?

Comment: Can you post your code that implements and calls the change stream?

Comment: I am looking for an answer that filters on the Strongloop loopback API

Comment: any solution here?